# Adding scala to existing java module in intellij

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I have a maven project with multiple java modules and I am trying to add scala to one of them. 
If I create a separate scala module, it works, but if I try to add scala to one of the java modules it doesn't work.

*What I did:*

I added Framework Support for Scala to one of the modules like it says [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2010/09/02/project-configuration-explained/). Then scala disappeared from that list.

I created a new folder named "scala" under main and a helloworld.scala file. I noticed that the scala folder is not blue like the java one, it's plain orange.

When I try to run the helloworld object, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: helloworld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
```

I don't have any exprience with intellij or maven (in case it matters). Been using eclipse all my life.

Using intellij 14 with scala 2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow by mistake, I've managed to solve it. All I had to do was right click on my scala directory and Mark Directory as Sources Root